# How to exclude a particular package form a dependency?

Tags: ant, dependencies, ivy

When specifing a dependencies using ant ivy, is there a way to exclude a particular package?

eg: I am putting a dependency to `MyJar.jar`

it has packages

```
com.test.one
com.test.one.first
com.test.one.second
com.test.two
etc.
```

I want to exclude the package `com.text.one.first`.

If there is a way, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivy downloads modules that contain one or more jar files (called artifacts) and which might in turn declare dependencies on other modules.

The [exclude](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/artifact-exclude.html) directive can be used to prevent the download of certain artifacts

```
<dependency name="myjar" rev="1.0">
  <exclude module="idontlikethismodule"/>
</dependency>
```

What ivy **cannot** do is open up a jar and only download certain packages.

If that is your requirement then I'd suggest downloading the jar and then repackaging it using the ANT [unzip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html) and [jar](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) commands.

Something like:

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[artifact].[ext]"/>
<unzip src="lib/myjar.jar" dest="build/unzip"/>
<jar destfile="build/mynewjar.jar" basedir="build/unzip" excludes="com.text.one.first"/>
```